# Installing GDR patches on top of CU

Tags: cumulative-update

I understand the difference between GDR and CU patches. I have to date only installed CU's but Windows update is suggesting a GDR update. Can I install GDR security patches and then install a newer CU whenever it is released? Not sure if you have to stick with GDR once one has been applied.